# VBA: Accidentally erased Presentations().Slides() Collection. How to reset?

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

VBA: I created an array called slides() and have overwritten the Presentations().Slides() collection. Here's the stupid thing I did:

```
Dim slides() As String
ReDim slides(size)
For b = 1 to size
With oApp.Presentations(oPres).Slides(slides(b)).Shapes(metrics(a)).Chart.ChartData
```

I've tried erasing the array and restarting PowerPoint to no effect. I can tell it's gone because when I type this:

```
Dim pages() As String 'Renamed to pages
ReDim pages(size)
For b = 1 to size
With oApp.Presentations(oPres).Slides(pages(b)).Shapes(metrics(a)).Chart.ChartData
```

It defaults to this (because the array was lowercase slides()):

```
With oApp.Presentations(oPres).slides(pages(b)).Shapes(metrics(a)).Chart.ChartData
```

Sadly this does not work (and returns an Object property error):

```
With oApp.Presentations(oPres).SlideRange(pages(b)).Shapes(metrics(a)).Chart.ChartData
```

How do I get the default Slides() Collection back?

PS It shouldn't make a difference, but this VBA code is housed in an Excel file. Thus the need for defining PowerPoint as an object (oApp).

Comment: You may have just learned the hard way of why backups are important. You can see if there is a temporary version of your workbook saved. `File > Open` and at the bottom **Recover Unsaved Workbooks**.

Comment: `C:\Users\%User%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\UnsavedFiles\ `

Comment: I didn't realize it was only Workbook-specific. I panicked and thought I had to completely reinstall Office because the settings were irreversibly changed. In that case, it's pretty easy to copy the code over to another Workbook. Thank you!